# Time counter MSQl

Tags: mysql, time

I have a column of TIME type in my db, the column is supposed to hold the sum of two other TIMEs, the problem is that when the number of hours of the result exceeds 24 hours the column is reseted to 00:00:00 again, instead of viewing 25:00:00 which is the result that I want to see, any help on how can I get that without changing the column type?

Comment: tame can take max of 24 hours isn't it

Comment: yeah but I don't want a real time, I just want to store the sum of hours, minutes and seconds in time format if that is possible :(

Comment: just keep the start date time and end date time , and take the difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store numbers that are bigger than a possible `time` then that data type is inappropriate.

Use another way to store the data like the sum of seconds. You could use an `unsigned int` for that.

Comment: but I need to use the time object in different operations as finding difference between tow times, so if I store my time as unsigned int can I convert it to time again when retrieving it from the db? if yes could you tell me how please?

Comment: No you can't convert 25 hours inta a valid time. That  is just out of range